# filter array of hashes with an array of keys ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby, hash

```
arr = [
  {
    :id=>2,
    :start=> "3:30",
    break: 30,
    num_attendees: 14
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    start: "3: 40",
    break: 40,
    num_attendees: 4
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    start: "4: 40",
    break: 10,
    num_attendees: 40
  }
]
```

When I do the following

```
arr.map do |hash|
 [ hash[:id], hash[:start] ]
end
```

returns

```
#=> [[2, "3:30"], [3, "3: 40"], [4, "4: 40"]]
```

Is there an elegant and efficient way of passing an array like `return_keys = [:id, :start]` and get the same above values rather than hard coding inside the `array.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you consider the following elegant and efficient?

```
arr.map { |h| h.values_at(:id, :start) }
#=> [[2, "3:30"], [3, "3: 40"], [4, "4: 40"]]
```

or

```
arr.map { |h| h.values_at(*return_keys) }
#=> [[2, "3:30"], [3, "3: 40"], [4, "4: 40"]]
```

Comment: It is elegant for sure but I have not benchmarking with anything else. So Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I find the following really expressive

```
keys = [:id, :start]
arr.map {|hash| hash.slice(*keys).values}
```

The `slice` method returns a hash only with the keys passed as parameters (which are preceded by the * operator to convert an array into keyword arguments and avoid hardcoding). Then, the `values` method gets just the values out of the hash